# load content onload insted of click

Tags: jquery, ajax

What would i change in the code to load content.php directly when the page load?

```
$("#refresh").click(function(evt) {
     $("#content").load("content.php")
     evt.preventDefault();
  })
})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#content").load("content.php")
})
```